# Doubts regarding receiving port based SMS using Socket connection in Android

Tags: android, sockets, sms, blackberry-android

I am trying to receive port based SMS with the below piece of code.

```
         serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
     Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
     try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                System.out.println("Reading Line is>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+line);
                break; 
            }           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception While Reading SMS>>>>>>>>>>"+e);                  
        }
```

Will it wait in the line of **serverSocket.accept();** until it gets the port based SMS,Is this correct behaviour or I am making any issue which hangs at that place.I am not able to move beyond it.

I am not able to test fully,I am not having option of testing it here,sending the port message.

Did anyone came across this issue.Any Info regarding this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try adding the while statement


`serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT); 

while(true){ 

     Socket client = serverSocket.accept(); 

     try { 

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())); 

            line = null; 

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) { 

                Log.d("ServerActivity", line); 

                System.out.println("Reading Line is>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+line);

                break; 

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception While Reading SMS>>>>>>>>>>"+e);

        }
}`

and for as long as it's true, it will wait for the client to send a message. It's been a while since i last did one of these [Working with Datagrams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html)